# Map multiple keys to one value

Tags: c#

I am trying to map a varying length of key values to one value and return the value based on any one of the several keys being provided.

For example:

```
    public const string GetDataCenterUrls = "getDataCenterUrls";
    public const string Get = "get";
    public const string Search = "search";
    public const string Upsert = "upsert";

    public const string value1= "value1";
    public const string value2 = "value2"

    public static readonly Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {GetDataCenterUrls, value1},
        {Get, value2},
        {Search, value2},
        {Upsert, value2},
    };
```

I want to avoid this and have something more like:

```
    public static readonly Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {GetDataCenterUrls, value1},
        {Get,Search,Upsert, value2},
    };
```

and return value by something like:

```
   dict[GetDataCenterUrls] === value1 //true
   dict[Get] == value2 //true
   dict[Search] == value2 //true
```

Have been looking at using Ilookup and a Dictionary with a list of keys but am still unsure of the best and most efficient way to accomplish this.

Saw this solution on Reddit to add an extension method to Dictionary but am not sure if there is a better way to achieve this:

```
 public static void Add<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> d, 
 IEnumerable<TKey> keys, TValue value)
{
    foreach (var key in keys) d.Add(key, value);
} 

 var d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 d.Add(new[] {"key1", "key2", "key3"}, "value");
```

Comment: Do you mean "varying length of key values" or "variable length of key values"? Do the length of the key vary as the program runs?

Comment: You could code a class that does what you want, more or less, but ultimately the underlying data structure will be like the dictionary in your first example.

Comment: I don't think there is a *better way* to add multiple rows having the same value. Your're right using the extension method.

Comment: The extension method is a good way of achieving what you want. I should go for that. What is holding you back? Why do you have doubts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Dictionary, it's always going to be one key mapping to one value.

The extension method you mentioned is merely shorthand for your first attempt, where each key is added separately. You could also call Dictionary.Add(item) several times after instantiating an empty dictionary.

There is very little performance difference in the two approaches, although using the extension method could result in slightly more expressive code if you want to make it clear that all these keys map to the same value.

If you are asking if it's okay to have a Dictionary like this, where multiple keys map to one value, there is no problem with it and I'm not aware of a more appropriate collection.

I will say that if you expect to update the values inside the Dictionary and expect all the related strings to change, you might want to use a class instead of a raw string. But you didn't ask about that, so I will refrain from elaborating.