# How to use enum with bitwise operator when the items already have values

Tags: c#, enums

I've the following `enum`:

```
[Flags]
public enum MouseMessage
{
    WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202,
    WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205,
    WM_WHEELBUTTONUP = 0x208,
    WM_XBUTTONUP = 0x020C
}
```

And what i want to do is something like this (e.Message contains an item from the `MouseMessage` `enum`):

```
switch (e.Message)
{
      case MouseMessage.WM_LBUTTONUP 
           | MouseMessage.WM_RBUTTONUP 
           | MouseMessage.WM_XBUTTONUP 
           | MouseMessage.WM_WHEELBUTTONUP:
                // Do something...
                break;
}
```

This does not work for me because the items in the `enum` already have values so I cannot benefit from the `Flags` attribute (i.e. 0,1,2,4 as values for the items).

I tried something but it didn't work either:

```
[Flags]
public enum MouseMessage
{
     WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202 | 0,
     WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205 | 1,
     WM_WHEELBUTTONUP = 0x208 | 2,
     WM_XBUTTONUP = 0x020C | 4
}
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE:
I want to use the `enum` like this (in a `Dictionary`)

Dictionary<MouseMessage, Action> dictionary = new Dictionary<MouseMessage, Action>()
{
{MouseMessage.WM_LBUTTONUP | MouseMessage.WM_RBUTTONUP | MouseMessage.WM_WHEELBUTTONUP |
MouseMessage.WM_XBUTTONUP, () => //...},
};

Note: this example is only to simplify my problem

Comment: Is it just falling between cases like `case X: case Y: case Z: whatever(); break`?

Comment: `[Flags]` attribute seems to be wrong for `MouseMessage`

Comment: @WiktorZychla I'm not sure what you mean exactly

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Why and how can I use it correctly in my case?

Comment: Flags is **purely** there to save memory. So I am not sure why you think it would help you logic. | I am betting you got stuck in a XY problem, and somehow thing that is the solution. Maybe pattern matching is the droid you are looking for?

Comment: @Christopher Ok thanks, how do I have to change my enum so that it does what I want?

Comment: You don't have to change the enum - change the `switch` instead (as @WiktorZychla mentioned in his comment) so that the "button up" cases all fall through to the same block of code.

Comment: Wrong way. You think forcing enums to do something they are not there for (and might be mathematically impossible), will sole your problem - that is your Y. But what is the X that got you to think that in the first place?

Comment: _"how do I have to change my enum so that it does what I want?"_ -- it is doubtful you can. You don't explain the context, but presumably these values are the predefined values from the Win32 native API. You shouldn't have marked the `enum` with `[Flags]`, and you can't modify their values, because those values have specific meaning to the native API. What you _can_ do is just put four `case` statements in succession, so that all four cases are handled by the same block of code, just as someone would do for any group of values to be handled the same. Why doesn't that work for you?

Comment: I've updated my question for clarity

Comment: Your question is still unclear. Why don't you just make multiple entries in the dictionary, one for each key? You can either instantiate the delegate value once and reuse it for each entry, or you can create it anew for each. In the latter case, you may find it more convenient to use a named method instead of lambda. Either way, there's no evidence in the question you tried _anything_ to address your problem, never mind any explanation of why the most obvious approaches don't satisfy your needs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Map multiple keys to one value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58210622/map-multiple-keys-to-one-value)

Comment: When I see this: `WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202 | 0,` it makes me wonder if you understand how the `|` operator works. What do you expect that is doing?

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the "button up" cases to have the same block of code in the `switch` statement, you can simply write the `switch` so that the cases all fall through to one code block:

```
switch (e.Message)
{
    case MouseMessage.WM_LBUTTONUP:
    case MouseMessage.WM_RBUTTONUP:
    case MouseMessage.WM_XBUTTONUP:
    case MouseMessage.WM_WHEELBUTTONUP:
    {
        // Do something...
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do complex comparision on each combination of enum values to match to one case, there is [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#using-pattern-matching-switch-statements). It is quite literally designed for that. If you want to check that `WM_LBUTTONUP || WM_XBUTTONUP` is up, no longer requires complicated if/else constructs.

And this Enumeration should in no way have enough combination that repalcing the switch/case with a dictionary is worth it.

If you are truly dead set on your soltion, make your Own Enumeration and translate between the two.

The input would be:

```
[Flags]
public enum MouseMessage
{
    WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202,
    WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205,
    WM_WHEELBUTTONUP = 0x208,
    WM_XBUTTONUP = 0x020C
}
```

The output would be:

```
[Flags]
public enum CustomMouseMessage
{
     WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202 | 0,
     WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205 | 1,
     WM_WHEELBUTTONUP = 0x208 | 2,
     WM_XBUTTONUP = 0x020C | 4
}
```

Mostly pseudo code:

```
CustomMouseMessage result;

switch(e.Message){
    case MouseMessage.WM_LBUTTONUP:
        result += CustomMouseMessage.WM_LBUTTONUP;
        break;
   //
}

return result;
```